# Разместить div во всю ширину

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разместить `div class="div2"` во всю ширину `div class="div1"`

```css
.div1 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.div2 {
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  display: block;
}

.div3 {
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3" style="width:1000px;">Блок</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3" style="width:800px;">Блок</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3" style="width:600px;">Блок</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3" style="width:400px;">Блок</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3" style="width:200px;">Блок</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А зачем у вас в div3 1000px задано?

Comment: @Pantera В div3 размещены элементы неизвестное количество.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, вам нужно написать так

```
.div2 {
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

Тогда так

```css
.div1 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
}

.div3 {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

.div4 {
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">
      <div class="div4" style="width: 100px">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
      <div class="div4" style="width: 1000px">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
      <div class="div4" style="width: 500px">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
      <div class="div4" style="width: 150px">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
      <div class="div4" style="width: 300px">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
      <div class="div4" style="width: 400px">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Посмотрите сейчас пожалуйста.

Comment: `inline-block`, а не просто `block`

Comment: div2 должен быть block. если inline-block все в один сливается.

Comment: а зачем вам тогда `white-space: nowrap`?

Comment: Старый участок кода был.

Comment: тогда попробуйте пояснить, как должны себя вести остальные элементы. более подробно

Comment: `div2` должен быть 100% от `div1`

Comment: Я смотрю, в изменили еще разметку, теперь каждый div3 обернут в div2 ...

Comment: в крайнем случае вы всегда можете изменить размер всех элементов через JS, найдя через него самый широкий

Comment: обновил ответ для вас

Comment: Есть, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток Владислав!
Как я вижу по примеру, `div2` занимает пространство `div1`
 но из-за того,
что в `div1` не указан параметр `overflow-x: hidden;`
браузер создает дополнительное пространство!

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду? Если ставить `overflow-x: hidden;` в `div1` тогда пропадет горизонтальный скролл.

Comment: Извините, я это имел ввиду. Я не знал что вам нужна полоска с низу. В данном случае, ваша задача нереалистичная, по скольку у вас в div3 задано width: 1000px; поскольку обычное ограничение overflow-x (или же по ширине) примерно 312px.

Comment: В div3 размещены элементы неизвестное количество. width может быть разным.

Comment: Отлично! Тогда уберите на время в div3 'width: 1000px;' и посмотрите на результат.

Comment: Убрал, поставил как будет более реально. Смотрите код в вопросе.